# How can i write code uploadfile and imgclassification in Blazor

Tags: blazor, mlmodel

i want to wknow how to  write code upload file with imgclassification and let them show result together. pls

i just start watch some cilp in youtube but it another version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try MudBlazor FileUpload

https://mudblazor.com/components/fileupload#event-options

Comment: it is very cool but I can't use MLModel.